# lightwave 3d 9.6 sdk trouble

Tags: c, sdk, 3d

Are there tutorials for the SDK (or at least an example), about how to create an export plugin (extract polygons from scene)?

Answer (score 1):

In Lightwave, you're not forced to write an export plugin to extract the polygons from a scene/object : the LWO and LWS are documented (enough) to parse them quite easily.

The file formats documentation are in `filefmts` folder of the SDK. You can find libs that parse Lightwave files also, such as [Open Asset Import library](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/).

If you still need to do it as a plugin, there's a sample plugin for *Modeler*, in the `sample/Modeler/Input-Output/vidscape` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a reasonable amount of LW export plugins on the web. Some of them are compiled `.p` plugins, but some are Python `.py` or LScript `*.ls`. Two latter can be edited and tweaked with text editor of your choice to individual needs quite easily.

There are wikis on the web about Lightwave API commands available from script as well.